# Designated Initializers with heap objects

Tags: c, struct

I have a large object with several fields which are const arrays which looks something like this:

```
struct test {
    const int vals[99999999];
};
```

I want to use a designated initializer to create the struct as the real struct has many fields.

As a result, I tried this

```
#include <stdlib.h>
struct test {
    const int vals[99999999];
};
int main()
{
    struct test first = {.vals[4]=4};
    return 0;
}
```

unsurprisingly this fails at runtime as the struct is too big to fit on the stack.

I then tried

```
#include <stdlib.h>
struct test {
    const int vals[99999999];
};
int main()
{

    struct test * t = malloc(sizeof(struct test));
    *t = (struct test){.vals[4]=4 };
    return 0;
}
```

This instead fails when I compile it with:

```
test.c:9:8 error: assignment of read-only location '*t'
```

Is it possible to use a designated initializer to create this struct?

Comment: Why does the array need to `const` if you intend to assign values later?

Comment: @usr I only assign values on initialisation

Answer (score 2):

No, not without casting away the `const` of course.

You can't say "this member cannot be assigned to" and then go ahead and assign to it without getting a warning.

I got this to work:

```
struct test *t = malloc(sizeof *t);
memcpy(t, &(struct test) { .vals[4] = 4 }, sizeof *t);
```

But I really don't think it's better; it probably costs as much since that value being copied has to exist somewhere (we are copying the full size of `*t` after all which includes all of the huge array).

Perhaps it's best to switch to having a global pre-initialized version, which you can access as needed:

```
static const struct test test_template = { .vals[4] = 4; };
```

Then you can do e.g.:

```
struct test foo = test_template;
```

This works, since it's initialization and not assignment. By making it global, it pushes the big "template object" into the global data, i.e. off the stack.

For a heap-allocated instance, you can do:

```
struct test * const foo = malloc(sizeof *foo);
memcpy(foo, &test_template, sizeof test_template);
```

This *will* overwrite the `const` data in `vals`, which isn't perhaps very pretty but should be safe. I think.

I had a previous attempt using an initializer function but that was faulty since it assigned to `vals`. Sorry!

Comment: Wouldn't this `t->vals[4] = 4;` give the "same" error, as the OP reports, that is by assigning to a read-only location?

Comment: The compound literal will be created on the stack as well and consequently blow up the latter as well.

Comment: I think the first idea with memcpy is what I needed.  Performance isn't really a problem in this case.

Comment: Please note that your two examples aren't equivalent. The first code will initialize all non-used items to zero, the second code will leave them as garbage.

Comment: @Lundin Good point, I didn't care enough. FIxed, and thanks of course.

Comment: @alk Gaah. Yes, it would. :( Fail. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In any case the `struct test` will blow up the stack, so you need to reduces this to what is manageable.

Try this:

```
struct Initialiser
{
   size_t index;
   int val;
}

void init_test(struct test * pt, struct Initialiser * initialiser, size_t size)
{
  while (size > 0)
  {
    --size;
    memcpy((char*)pt + initialiser[size].index * sizeof *(pt->vals) , 
      &initialiser[size].val, 
      sizeof pt->vals[initialiser[size].index]);
  }
}


int main(void)
{
  struct Initialiser initialiser[] = 
  {
    {1, 42},
    {4, 4},
    ...
  }   

  struct test * t = malloc(sizeof *t);

  init_test(t, initialiser, sizeof initialiser / sizeof *initialiser);

  ...
```

If the `struct Initialiser` as defined above also grows to huge, use several with each being defined in a separate context/scope.

Answer (score 0):

It probably doesn't make much sense to mix initializers with dynamic memory allocation to begin with. Most often, initializers refer to start-up conditions, while dynamic allocation always happen at run-time.

I can't come up with any reason why you wouldn't be able to do this:

```
struct test * t = malloc(sizeof(struct test));
t->vals[4] = 4;
```

This is much faster and consumes way less memory than any solution revolving around memcpy and temporary stack objects. Creating a temporary compound literal with the size of 99999999 ints is madness. You shouldn't write blatantly inefficient programs just for the sake of using designated initializers.

If you need to zero-out unused items, then use `calloc`.

Comment: @DavidBowling Well of course you can't write to a read-only memory location in run-time. If the OP needs to do that, they obviously have to remove the `const` keyword.

Comment: @DavidBowling One possible solution to keep the read-only property would be to allocate and initialize the struct, then after that's done, only de-reference it through a `const struct test*`.

Answer (score 0):

In most implementations of C, the offset of an array within a structure will be independent of its size.  While the Standard does not require that, and as a consequence cannot require that the common portion of two arrays within a structure behave as a Common Initial Sequence, for decades compilers supported constructs like:

```
struct thing2 { int size; int data[2]; };
struct thing3 { int size; int data[3]; };
struct thing4 { int size; int data[4]; };
struct thing_arbitrary { int size; int data[99999]; };

void print_thing_contents(void *p)
{
  int i;
  struct thing_arbitrary *it = (thing_arbitrary*)p;
  for (int i=0; i<it->size; i++)
    printf("%d ", it->dat[i]);
}
```

with `print_thing_contents()` being able to accept structures of any of the
indicated kinds provided the `size` member was set appropriately.

Using that pattern, one could create initialized constants using structures
that fit the above pattern, e.g.

```
struct { int size; int data[5]; } my_fiver = {5,{1,2,3,4,5}};
```

and use them with `print_thing_constants`.  For C99, it would make sense to use a flexible array member in `thing_arbitrary`, and the aliasing rules would require something like:

```
struct my_fiver_type { int size; int data[5]; } my_fiver = 
  {5,{1,2,3,4,5}};
union my_fiver_dummy_union 
  { struct my_fiver_type v1; struct thing_arbitrary v2; }
```

to let the compiler know that things of type `struct my_fiver_type` might have their common initial sequence accessed using pointers of type `struct thing_arbitrary`.  Unfortunately, the Standard only guarantees that `size` will be treated as members of the CIS, and provides no way to extend that to the first five items of `dat`.  Further, while the above should be all the notice a quality compiler should need to recognize aliasing between the two types, the only way gcc will support such code is by disabling aliasing analysis altogether via `-fno-strict-aliasing` (which may be a good idea anyway until gcc starts honoring the Standard).